# SSIS Suddenly Requires DCOM Permissions

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msdtc

I have recently deployed some SSIS packages. I made a job to run them one after another. However, I am now allowed to use MSDTC. So I chained the jobs together like I have done before, but now I am faced with an error message about DCOM. All Internet research points to insufficient permissions on the MSDTC component, but I am worried this is going the wrong way.

Any idea how I can "reset" the need for MSDTC for this package?

Comment: If you're using transactions inside the SSIS packages, they are employed using MS DTC (distributed transaction coordinator). See more [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/).

Answer (score 1):

The job has several steps. In the step that ran the package, I had to select "SQL Server" as the package source instead of "SQL Server Package Store". This stopped the use of MSDTC.